# LIKE TableName in a Join

Tags: sql, join, teradata, sql-like

I'm joining two sets on unions with an on clause based on the tablenames. The tablenames differ just for a prefix but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using Teradata.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT a.TableName, b.TableName, 
FROM 
(SELECT abc as TableName FROM db.abc UNION
SELECT def as TableName FROM db.2) AS def
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT ghi as TableName FROM db2.ghi UNION
SELECT lmn as TableName FROM db3.lmn) AS b
ON ','||b.TABLENAME||',' LIKE '%,' ||TRIM(a.TABLENAME)||', %';
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: 1st subquery has table alias def, 2nd sub-query has no table alias at all. But you ON conditions has tables a and b.

Comment: Do not store values as comma separated values. Normalize your structure.

Comment: @jarlh forgot to add it in the sample code. I added it now

Comment: @GurV Could you please explain?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The desired result is to have a table with on one column tablenames from one database and on the other tablenames from another database. The table names in the two databases are mappes as in prefix_tablename = tablename.

Comment: This is not the way to go with Teradata.

Comment: There's a space in the final `||', %';`